# Holding a Packet

Tags: iptables, filter, packet

I am trying to alter a stream of packets by temporarily holding a specific packet.

For example, if the packet are numbered 1,2,3,4,5, and so on, I want to temporarily store packet 2 so that I can release packet 2 when I want it. that is the client will get 1,3,,4,5,$some random number,2

Can you please help me to find the #HOLDPACKETMAGICCOMMAND packet 3 until I run the #RELEASEPACKETMAGICCOMMAND?

I had a look at the implementation of the statistic properties of the iptables to target specific packet but I could only find Reject/Drop. Unfortunately these 2 delete the packet instead of storing it in a restorable array like storage.

I had a look at TCPFLOW but it only stores the copy of the original packet to a file instead to a memory.

Is there any other better way other than trying to find the MAGICPACKETHOLD command in the iptables?

Comment: Perhaps you have more luck if you search info about the packages that use [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture network data. It's not a solution, it's a simple pointing. Hope you can do what you want, it's very interesting!

Comment: hi k.Cyborg, Thanks for the encouragement! at the moment I am leaning towards pfifo_fast or TBF as per below answers/comment. Please CMIIW but my understanding is wireshark uses PCAP and it does not allow retrieval of the packet. What do you think?

Comment: If I'm really honest with you: I think thath what you're trying to do es very difficult, it's gonna take very butt hours (in my language butt hours is a analogy, some like: it's gonna to take and consume your time), but in the other side is a very interesting project. Just a tip: leave the links when you wrote something specific, if not I (and others) that may be don't know about that subject feels a little confuse. Greetings!!!

Comment: `-m connbytes --connbytes-mode packets --connbytes 2:2` to get the 2nd packet and using this for the delay: https://serverfault.com/questions/701228/delaying-packets-with-libnetfilter-queue (perhaps not the accepted answer) should give you something

Comment: @k.Cyborg butt hours seems like an acceptable unit of consumed time lol. And yes, I should leave some link, please excuse my newbie/babyness.

Comment: @A.B From your link, can I know why do you prefer not the accepted answer? Life is a bit busy at the moment for me, but at least I can give you some thumbs up for the connbytes idea. It sounds more accurate then Token Bucket Filtering method in the below answers. And yes, I was also raised to say thank you to nice people. so, thank you!

Comment: Because the accepted answer (auto answer from the OP) tells about using raw sockets, which could quickly go into stackoverflow topics instead of here. THe answer from vmx tells "You don't need to do NF_DROP verdict on incoming packet and resend it via raw socket. You can hold packet in your own queue, and verdict it later (say, after some delay)." . He even provides an example application

Comment: thanks once more A.B , now if only I can get my rig working and spare some time on trying this...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such concept as to hold a packet in networking.
A packet either gets to its destination or gets lost (Reject/Drop).

Additionally, in TCP, packets must be in order, if packets are received out of order, they are re-ordered. Any packet missing will halt reception.

And if it were possible to place a packet in a buffer, the receiving application will simply ask for its re-transmission. The application will try to restore order and continue the transmission from the specific packet that got lost.

So, even if it were possible to hold a packet, it won't work to change the transmission.

Comment: hello, I have just read on 2 buffer like filtering with pfifo_fast or Token Bucket Filter (TBF) and yes i think it would help to "induce" (not sure of the correct term) of the "lost" packet retransmission. However, I am not sure how long of a delay would trigger a retransmission, could you please guide me for that? Thank you beforehand

Comment: The re-transmission is called in matter of milliseconds, never more than 10 seconds (if the connection is active). That is all the time you may delay a communication.

Comment: thanks! you answer seems to be one part of the answer to my original question. Now if only I can find a proper way to delay a specific packet. Currently discussing it with U880D. Once more, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the package Linux [Traffic Control](http://lartc.org/howto/index.html) (`tc`) which is part of `iproute2`, at least with it it is possible to randomly slow down (parameter `delay`), `reorder` and drop (parameter `loss`) packets. Good starting points might be https://wiki.debian.org/TrafficControl, [Use Traffic Control](https://www.excentis.com/blog/use-linux-traffic-control-impairment-node-test-environment-part-2) and [how to create filters](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.filters.html).

Comment: Hello there, thanks for the link and after reading for a while, I come up with this idea. Can you please tell me your opinion on it?

Comment: Hello there, thanks for the link and after reading for a while, I come up with this idea. Can you please tell me your opinion on it? First I will use the U32 selector to specify which packet that I want to filter (I know my target packet content, etc). Then I will use either pfifo_fast , with modified packet length of 1 set through ifconfig. Alternatively I am thinking of Token Bucket Filter (TBF) with a very small bucket size and very slow rate. with the TBF I think the timing would be more accurate. However, please CMIIW. Thank you

Comment: Since I haven't tried it in such way yet, I personally would start with delaying a specific packet as mentioned under https://serverfault.com/questions/389290/.

Comment: Heya, so do you mean filtering the specific packet by the TOS octet which will filter the data into the 3 bands? My understanding is that my target data (EAPOL handshake message) would be in band 0 top priority so that "banding" does not help, or it it just my thoughtless thought haha? P.S hopefully one day I will be able to help you back!